# Facet_wrap not working with of geom_bar but working with geom_point

Tags: r, geom-bar, facet-wrap

My facet_wrap plot works fine with points, but when I want to change these points to bars it does not work. scale_y_reverse.

```
ggplot(data=depth, aes(x=value, y=Depth)) + facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=7) + labs(x="Macroalgae genes (TPM)", y="Depth (m)") +scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0.03, 0.03), labels=layers) + geom_point(aes(color = variable), shape=1) + theme_bw() + theme(plot.margin=unit(x=c(0.3,0.8,0.3,0.3), units="cm"), 
                 axis.text=element_text(size=13, family="Times New Roman", color="black"), 
                 axis.title = element_text(size = 20, family="Times New Roman"), strip.background = element_blank(), 
                 strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=13, lineheight=5.0, family="Times New Roman"), 
                 legend.position="none", panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), 
                 panel.spacing.y=unit(0.3, "lines"), panel.spacing.x=unit(0.15, "lines"),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                 panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), 
                 axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

How do I change the points to bars?

[Plot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Hd6.png)

Thanks!

Comment: geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(y=Depth), position=position_dodge() does not work